# Initializing a float array with memset

Tags: c, memset

This is the code that I want to try to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float arry[3] = {0};

    memset(arry, (int) 10.0, 3*sizeof(float));

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I want to see if it's possible to use memset to make every entry of an array to be a number other than 0. However, After stepping through that line, the array contents change to a very small number (0). I wonder what I'm doing wrong in this case with using the memset() function. I hope this isn't a duplicate post, as none of the suggested related questions as I'm typing this appears to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Casting a double to an int just creates the binary number 00001010 (10 in binary), and that is the value that is memset'ed. Since it's a char, each of your floats is actually receiving the bit pattern 00001010 00001010 00001010 00001010.

Comment: i.e. it only makes sense to use it to reset the entries of an array to zeros, practically speaking?

Comment: That or if you are setting up a char array that has some other value that is relevant.

Comment: Or any single byte value. The most common is probably 0, but 0xFF is also likely to be used a lot.

Comment: Or any integer (short, int, long etc.) value if you need all bytes of each integer the same. 0 and 0xFF being the most likely candidates.

Comment: As an example, I just programmed a use of this. It is a structure of parameters that get passed to some GUI dialog of sorts, I memset the whole structure to 0x00 since that bit pattern works for everything (pointers, floats, etc.) before setting only the couple fields I care about.

Answer (score 15):

[Memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) takes a int, but casts it to an unsigned char, and then fills each byte of float (sizeof(float) is probably 4) with that bit pattern. If this is c++, prefer [fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

//...

fill (arry,arry+3,10.0);
```

Comment: And if you're in C not C++, then look about for platform-specific memset variants which write larger patterns than a single char. There's memset_pattern4 for instance if you have it. Or SIMD instructions.

Answer (score 8):

No. memset takes a single byte and writes it to the array. A float is a multi-byte type.

EDIT: Yes, I know memset takes an int. But it only uses an unsigned char (a single byte) to fill with.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just a simple `for` loop?

Comment: The need for speed is one answer.

Comment: All memset's going to do is set the memory one byte at the time.  A for loop will zip through sizeof(arry) bytes sizeof(float) bytes at a time.  And without the overhead of a function call!

Comment: @Mark Jones: The difference is that memset can take advantage of the inbuilt string handling instructions of the CPU, making the operation somewhat faster.

Answer (score 3):

Actually your try is a little bit misleading, memset works on bytes.. actually using a float for memset value doesn't make any sense!

The float format just has 23+1 bits for mantissa and 8 bits for exponent.. when you write raw bytes values (using memset) inside a float you don't know what you are obtaining because you are setting values that will be interpreted in a different way!

In your snippet you also cast it to (int) turning a 4-bytes float containing 10.0f in a 4-bytes integer containing the value 10.. but as said before if you memset a float with 10 (= 0x0a) you'll end up obtaining 0x0A0A0A0A that is not 10.0f in float format, it can be whatever  value (also something very near to 0, like in your case).

Actually **`memset`** is useful when you want to initialize an array of chars (since you obtain effectively that value for every char because they are 1 byte long) or when you want to set everything to 0 (NULL) that works for every basic kind of data..